# how to route network traffic from wireless interface to a second wireless interface and a 3G/4G usb dongle on the same computer

Tags: wireless-networking, router, debian, iptables

I have a computer running a debian based distribution with three network interfaces: two wireless (wlan0 and wlan1) and the third one is an usb dongle for 3G/4G network access. I want to archive the following configuration:

- wlan0 must be configured as an access point to give internet access to other exterior devices (i have been able to use hostapd to give my computer a SSID and it can authenticate devices using WPA2)
- wlan1 must have internet access provided by an exterior access point.
- The usb dongle must have internet access provided by a cellular data carrier
- The network traffic from exterior devices connected to wlan0 must be routed from wlan0 to wlan1 or the usb dongle, giving priority to wlan1 (to minimize the use of cellular data)
- Any program that runs inside the computer, must have also internet access using wlan1 or the usb dongle, with priority to wlan1

In short, i would like that the internet access is routed just in the same way as it is routed in a cell phone device with wifi and 3G/4G internet, but with the added functionality that the computer is also an access point for external devices that connect to it using the interface wlan0. I have not found any tutorial on the internet that works with this specific setting.

Does anyone know what routing rules must be used ? Are there any user space programs that can help me make this task easier ?

Comment: You are using the wrong hardware for this - although it is possible. I would use any LEDE/OpenWrt compatible router that has a USB port - Then you have a system where what you want to do is available far quicker. Archer C5 from TP-Link is a good example of a compatible router.

Comment: I really need to do this with the computer and the three network interfaces. Is it really very hard ?

Comment: I ended up programming a small python service, which test for network connectivity on wlan1. If the test success, then the services configures network traffic from wlan0 to wlan1 (using python-iptables). In case that the test fails, then the services configures network traffic to go from wlan1 to the usb dongle.